# str.format() with lazy dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, lazy-loading

I want to use `str.format()` and pass it a custom lazy dictionary.

`str.format()` should only access the key in the lazy dict it needs.

Is this possible?

Which interface needs to be implemented by the lazy_dict?

**Update**

This is not what I want:

```
'{0[a]}'.format(d)
```

I need something like this:

```
'{a}'.format(**d)
```

Need to run on Python2.7

Comment: "`str.format()` should only access the key in the lazy dict it needs" It *already* does this. It does *not* iterate over all the dictionary!

Comment: @Bakuriu But in the case of `**d`, the converstion accesses all items.

Answer (score 1):

For doing `'{a}'.format(**d)`, especially the `**d` part, the "lazy" dict is transformed into a regular one. Here happens the access to *all* keys, and `format()` can't do anything about it.

You could craft some proxy objects which are put in place of the elements, and on string access they do the "real" work.

Something like

```
class LazyProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, prx):
        self.prx = prx
    def __format__(self, fmtspec):
        return format(self.prx(), fmtspec)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.prx())
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prx())
```

You can put these elements into a dict, such as

```
interd = { k, LazyProxy(lambda: lazydict[k]) for i in lazydict.iterkeys()}
```

I didn't test this, but I think this fulfills your needs.

After the last edit, it now works with `!r` and `!s` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__format__` method (Python 3 only). See the doc [here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__format__#object.__format__).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass a custom dictionary, that would compute values only when needed. First, we're looking for implementation of `__getitem__()`:

```
>>> class LazyDict(object):
...    def __init__(self, d):
...        self.d = d
...    def __getitem__(self, k):
...        print k             # <-- tracks the needed keys
...        return self.d[k]
...
>>> d = D({'a': 19, 'b': 20})
>>> '{0[a]}'.format(d)
a
'19'
```

This shows that only key `'a'` is accessed; `'b'` is not, so you already have your lazy access.

But also, any object attribute is usable for `str.format` this way, and using `@property` decorator, you can access function results:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 19
        self.b = 20
    def __getitem__(self, var): 
        return getattr(self, var)
        # this command lets you able to call any attribute of your instance,
        # or even the result of a function if it is decorated by @property:
    @property
    def c(self):
        return 21
```

Example of usage:

```
>>> m = MyObject()
>>> '{0[c]}'.format(m)
'21'
```

But note that this also works, making the formating string a little bit specific, but avoid the need for `__getitem__()` implementation.

```
>>> '{0.c}'.format(m)
'21'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question. I am very sorry, that I did not explain my thoughts in more details. Please look at the question again.

Comment: @guettli Well, now I have no idea how to answer to your question; actually, it appears I'm not even able to get the interest of your question :-/